# How to insert millions of random rows in Cassandra using CQL?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

In PostgreSQL, I use the query below. How can I do this in Cassandra?

```
INSERT INTO public.core_post(id, created, title, message, latitude, longitude, owner_id)
SELECT uuid_generate_v4(), now(), 'Hello!', 'What?', null, null, 1 FROM generate_series(1,1000000);
```

Comment: why do you need that?

Comment: looked at the cassandra-stress tool?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't with pure CQL.

But you can use external tools like presto DB apache drill or hand made software.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a python script that will connect to you cluster, then create a loop in which you can create batch statements with random data in your columns and then execute the ingestion.

```
from cassandra.query import BatchStatement, SimpleStatement
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
import random

# Connect to the cluster
cluster = Cluster(['ip', 'ip'])
session = cluster.connect()


for i in range(10)
    # Create your random data
    my_first_data = random.choice(range(15))
    my_second_data = random.choice(range(50))

    # instanciate a batch statement
    batch = BatchStatement()

    # create a new query with your random data
    batch.add(SimpleStatement("INSERT INTO my_table (data1, data2) VALUES (%s, %s)"), (my_first_data, my_second_data))

# Execute all the queries 
session.execute(batch)
```

Comment: This answer commits two Cassandra 'sins': 1) For better performance it should be a prepared statement, and 2) batch will actually _hurt_ performance unless all writes are to the same partition and it is an unlogged batch.

Comment: There's also a fatal bug that means the example above won't work anyway - the batch is created inside the loop, so only the very last insert will actually be executed!

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, indeed the session.execute could be in the loop to execute the query in the loop. 
When I wrote the script 5 years ago though, the purpose was to sent thousands of queries at the same time and thus to send all the queries at the same time mimicking several users. In the end I added a multithread in my code but the principle remained the same. :)